# Is $C(\mathbb{R}_+ , E)$, space of all continuous mappings $f$ of $[0,\infty)$ into a Polish space $E$, locally compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $C(\mathbb{R}_+ , E)$ be the space of all continuous mappings $f$ of $[0,\infty)$ into a Polish space $E$, endowed with the topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}_+$. I know this space is Polish, but is it also locally compact Hausdorff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what polish space is, but in case if $\Bbb{R} $ is a Polish space then $C(\Bbb R_+ , \Bbb R) $ is not locally compact, since $B(0, \delta)$, the closed ball,  is not compact

Since $B(0, \delta)$ is not compact in $C[0,1].$ Therefore there is a sequence of continuous functions, say $\{ f_n \}_{n \in N}$ which does not have convergent subsequence in $B(0, \delta)  \subseteq C[0,1] $ Now define

$$ g_n (x) =\left\{\begin{matrix}
 f_n (x)&  x \in [0,1]  \\ 
 f_n(1)&   x \in (1,+\infty) 
\end{matrix}\right. $$

Then we have $ \{ g \}_{n \in N}  \subseteq B(0, \delta)  \subseteq C(\Bbb R_{+} , \Bbb R ) $ does not  have convergent subsequence in $B(0,  \delta) \subseteq C(\Bbb R_{+} , \Bbb R ) $ 
.

Comment: Polish means complete separable metric space. Can you explain why $B(0,\delta)$ is not compact in this case?

Comment: Do you agree $B(0,\delta)$ in   $C[0,1]$ with supremum norm is not compact? 

Since it is a infinite dimensional normed space.

Comment: Yes, but how does this conclude the argument?